# Removing Parent Page URL While Keeping the Navigation Intact

Tags: pages, navigation, child-pages, breadcrumb

So here is the current format:

site.com/parent-page/child-page/ - example 0

Child-page is ranking higher than parent-page, which is not what I want. So, I have a solution.

site.com/parent-page/ - example 1

site.com/child-page/ - example 2

In the child-page I will have a breadcrumb on the top, like this:

Home -> Parent Page -> Child Page

The parent page already has a virtual SILO, so we are building another virtual SILO for child page. My question is this:

Q1. How can I remove the parent page URL from example 0 to make it look like example 2?

Q2. How can I make sure child-page still points to parent-page after implementing Q1?